Is there entry level software that can simulate 3D speaker cabinet design with computational fluid dynamics?
I'm looking for a program or toolkit that can aid in designing speaker boxes that allows you to perform simulations of their acoustic response. Something that supports audio frequency computational fluid dynamics.
There are many very old programs that can give you numerical results, programs like WinISD or HornResp, but they are very old and come with their own bugs on modern OS's. Interestingly one of them has a 2D fluid simulation, its very low res but an example of it can be see at https://www.falstad.com/ripple/ I'm wondering if there is any more modern software that features this kind of simulation but in 3D.
I'm aware of several cad solutions (ANSYS, SimScale, COMSOL), however most of them are so expensive they don't even have a price, you must "send an enquiry" and engineering solutions are probably overkill. I'm also aware of OpenFoam but haven't found any tutorials that feature acoustic simulation. There are also a few room scale acoustic simulators for simulating venue acoustics but I'm unsure if any of these can go down to the scale of a speaker and box. Something that is rentable from month to month would also be within budget. I'm also aware of AKABAK which is probably what I'm looking for but the price is far from home enthusiast range.
Ideally the features I'm after is something that I can place a virtual speaker in a 3D cabinet and get frequency responses, amount of chuffing (vortex shredding) at ports and a visualisation of how the unit projects sound. Anything more that that might be a plus (something that can import speaker parameters would be a bonus) but would probably be wasted on me at this stage.
I'm open to suggestions on if its possible to set these kinds of things up in OpenFoam or other software (matlab or the like).
Thank you for your time
